# Error: Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, sharp

I'm getting this error when I try to run gatsby develop, so far I've tried:

1. npm install --ignore-scripts=false --verbose sharp
2. npm install --platform=win32 --arch=x64 sharp
3. npm clean cache --force
4. gatsby clean
5. deleting node_modules, package-lock.json and then npm install
6. updating to the latest node, npm and gatsby version

this is the specific error:

Error: Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module
The specified module could not be found.
\node_modules\sharp\build\Release\sharp-win32-x64.node

I checked for that specific module in that specific folder and it's there... Any ideas? No errors or whatsoever when I tried all the above solutions.

Comment: Were you able to fix this? Running into the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately no, the only things left to do are trying older versions of node and as a last resource, formatting the pc.

Comment: same here on windows 8.1, it works on linux debian

Comment: @Sheldeeb I managed to solve the problem reinstalling Windows and then, installing everything Gatsby requires to properly work using Chocolatey... Among these things: Python and Visual C++ build tools.

Comment: I don't use Gatsby and it very difficult now to reinstall windows, but I want to know what exactly should I fix to make Sharp work @ivanatias